# get String from "for loop" when I use break

Tags: java, loops, break, minecraft, bukkit

I have the following code block (it's a plugin for bukkit server[minecraft game])

```
            msg = lang.getString("Kick", "null"); //default msg.
            msg = msg.replace("\\n", "\n");
            int i = 0;
            Player target = null;
            for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-")){
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int ii = i+1; ii < args.length; ii++) {
                            sb.append(args[ii]).append(" ");
                    }
                    msg = sb.toString().trim(); // - that msg I need
                    break;
                } 
                target = (Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[i]));
                target.kickPlayer(msg); // <--- here
```

How to get "msg" string from loop.
code must work like: 
Player type command /command target1 target2 - r e a s o n
then code:
Get target1
Get target2
Get target3 but target3 is '-'. then every args after '-' is reason (msg). (then i must break a loop for getting player) 
And kick target1 with reason(msg). kick target2 with reason(msg). 
But if player type /command target1 target2... target999
Then just kick it with default reason.

Comment: can you repeat that question ? whats wrong with what you have now ?

Comment: At the first view your code should work fine. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Why is that `break` even there when you still want to use `msg` within the loop?

Comment: @user2250333 I updated my post. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the way you go through the arguments is not the best in this case. Use `for (String argument : args)` instead. And another thing: You cannot execute code in a loop after `break`.

Now to your problem. You want to go through the arguments and check if it is `-` or not. Everything after `-` should be added to a `String`. That string has a default value. If there is a `-` the default value should be removed and the value should be everything after `-`.

```
boolean read = false;
String msg = "default message";
List<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String argument : args) {
    if (!read && !argument.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
        players.add(argument);
    } else if (!read && argument.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
        read = true;
        msg = "";
    } else {
        msg += argument;
    }
}

for (String player : players) {
    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(player);
    target.kickPlayer(msg);
}
```

To do this, you need a boolean, the message string and a list where all the target names should be saved in. This code goes through all the arguments.

If the boolean is false AND the argument is not `-`, the argument gets saved in the players list. Else if the boolean is false but the argument is `-` the boolean gets set to true and the default value of the string gets removed. Else (the argument is part of the message) the argument gets attached to the string.

After all there is another loop where the plugin goes through all the players added to the list and kicks them showing them the entered message.

Cheers!

Comment: That wrong. and not work. code must work like: 
Player type command /command target1 target2 - r e a s o n
then code:
Get target1
Get target2
Get target3 but target3 is '-'. then every args after '-' is reason (msg).
And kick target1 with reason(msg). kick target2 with reason(msg). 
But if player type /command target1 target2... target999
Then just kick it with default reason.

Comment: I see. You should use a `boolean` and a `String` and check if the argument is `-`. When it is set the `boolean` to `true`. If the boolean was false before set the message string to `""`, else attach the argument to the string if the boolean is set to true.

Comment: 'before set the message string to '""'" hyym but the msg is string for all code. is for getting messages from language file (English or Polish)

Comment: You can do it like this: `msg = lang.getString("Kick", "null");` instead of `String msg = "default message";`. As long as there is no message entered via the command the string will not change.

Comment: works with one problem. in previous code i have' sb.append(args[ii]).append(" ") 'where and how add something like this in that code? just that append(" ") because if reason is eg: ' for blah blah ' then i get ' forblahblah '

Comment: I'm glad to help you. You also can change the line `msg += argument;` to `msg += argument + " ";` instead of `concat(" ")` but that's up to you. ;)